# Apache POI HSSF/XSSF support for newer Versions of Excel

Tags: apache-poi

Currently im working on a project which includes the Apache POI to read and write Excel files.

Im looking for a source that basically says that the POI (HSSF/XSSF) works for newer versions of Excel as well, since it says on the official website that HSSF supports Excel 97-2007. Yet i got Excel 2016 and when i'm trying to read data out of the file it's working just fine. Im Struggling to find something because i don't know where to look, and my first language isn't english so skimming through the changelogs is really hard for me.

Please let me know if this was a stupid question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/ basically answers your question. The default file format in Excel 2016 is OOXML based .xlsx file format - the same as all versions of Excel since 2007. On Stackoverflow, it is normally expected that you ask more specific questions. My advice would be to try the POI samples with your own files and come back if you have problems.

Comment: That said, POI is not compiled with the latest version of the OOXML schema, so some of the latest additions from Excel 2016 may not work for you. But anything generated by POI can be read by Excel 2016. Try what you need, and ask us about what doesn't work.